# How to calculate the ratio between column(2) and column(3) while the value of column(1) is the same in R?

Tags: r

Consider this dataset:

```r
example = data.frame("person"= rep(c(1:3), each = 4),
                     "expected income" = c(seq(140,250,10)),
                     "income" = c(seq(110,220,10)))
print(example)
```

I need to calculate the ratio between column(2) in year(i) and column(3) in year (i+1).
Furthermore the ratio has to be done only when the "person" (col1) is the same.
Instead of the ratio between the "expected income" and the "income" of two different people I need an NA.
It has to be done generically since it is just a semplification of a dataset with more than 60000 rows.

Comment: where is the `year` information in your data?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example with what you do and do-not want to happen. Your questions is vague about what exactly you are looking for, maybe the mean ratio of expected to actual for each person? (If that's it then `example %>% group_by(person) %>% summarize(r=mean(expected/income)`).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
example %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(ratio = lag(expected.income)/income) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   person expected.income income ratio
    <int>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1             140    110 NA   
 2      1             150    120  1.17
 3      1             160    130  1.15
 4      1             170    140  1.14
 5      2             180    150 NA   
 6      2             190    160  1.12
 7      2             200    170  1.12
 8      2             210    180  1.11
 9      3             220    190 NA   
10      3             230    200  1.1 
11      3             240    210  1.10
12      3             250    220  1.09
```

---

Alternative:

```
example %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(ratio = expected.income/lead(income)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 4
   person expected.income income ratio
    <int>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1             140    110  1.17
 2      1             150    120  1.15
 3      1             160    130  1.14
 4      1             170    140 NA   
 5      2             180    150  1.12
 6      2             190    160  1.12
 7      2             200    170  1.11
 8      2             210    180 NA   
 9      3             220    190  1.1 
10      3             230    200  1.10
11      3             240    210  1.09
12      3             250    220 NA
```

It carries the same information, just in different rows now.

Comment: I was about to do the same thing, but I was interpreting the OP to mean that the ratio should be in the same row as `expected.income`, which means it might instead be `expected.income / lead(income)`. Semantically the same numbers are produced, but offset 1 row.

Comment: Yes, thought about the same (and actually had this as my first try, but then decided for the lag way), but depending on TO‘s preference I can easily adjust this.

Comment: Thank you, the alternative verion is exactly what i need.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please consider accepting this (or any other) answer, so that others can benefit from this information as well.